# Are Midoriya and other quirkless people actually quirkless?

Tags: my-hero-academia

We all know Midoriya aka Deku born without quirk. But the first person who tells Deku that he's quirkless is this kindly looking doctor
[image]

We are all made to believe that Deku is quirkless by this doctor. Then later in the manga we finally get a little hint about this doctor, there's 1 doctor that are very similar, named Daruma Ujiko who is working for All for One.  https://bokunoheroacademia.fandom.com/wiki/Daruma_Ujiko

Is it possible that this Doctor stole Deku's quirk when he diagnosed our boy (related to All for One abbility)? My further question is, is it possible that actually all people in BNHA are born with quirk, but got stolen at young age by certain people and made to believe that they are quirkless?

Comment: That's a really interesting theory. You have my upvote. However, IIRC, this has not yet been confirmed by the manga.

Comment: Take note that the wiki does not acknowledge that he was the same doctor as Midoriya's when he was told he had no quirk (it was mentioned that his first manga appearance was only on Chapter 59. There are also some minute details that are different: the shape of his face, for example. Daruma has a much rounder face whereas this doctor has a pear-shaped face. Although, yes, it's also possible they are one and the same.

Comment: @W.Are yes you are right, the wiki says they are similar, so messed up lmao

Comment: If it's true, then it's probably something the manga is building up to, so no-one would know (except for the author).

Answer (score 4):

I’ll wait for the manga to comment on Midoriya, but the other major “quirkless” character we are shown is the original One for All. He was All for One’s brother and thought to have no quirk. However, we soon find out that his quirk was one with no effect - the ability to transfer quirks. It requires the action of All for One forcibly transferring a quirk to him to manifest itself.

I believe that other quirkless people have similar quirks that don’t manifest because they don’t have the right stimuli.